# rowspan with css

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

my  website layout uses a table like this.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" rowspan="2" style="padding-right:41px;">
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" width="440px">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" width="440px">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

a nav bar on the left which takes up two rows and two columns.

How can I translate this to CSS? how do i handle rowspan?

I've read that using a table will slow down rendering the page, because the browser has to render all columns first before it can render the table. so if one column contains 1000 nested divs the other columns have to wait to render. Is this true?

Comment: You have two questions here.  Please post the speed issue as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

CSS:

```
div#navBar {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 41px;
}
div.nonHeader {
    width: 440px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navBar"></div>
<div id="header" class="nonHeader"></div>
<div id="bodyText" class="nonHeader"></div>
```

That forces the navbar to the left of the header and body text divs, which are fixed-width.

I do wonder if you don't want the navBar div to be fixed-width and the other two flexible, however.

Comment: This doesn't accomplish the same layout as the table example shown above.  In the table example, the spanned row will occupy the same height as 2 rows.  In the CSS example the navBar will only occupy the height required.  Furthermore, if the header & bodyText are longer than the navBar the content will wrap around the navBar.